# Add line break for string assignment (For html rendering)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a new line like so:

```
let myString= "";
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(response)) {
   myString += response + "\n";
}
```

But the HTML outputs space instead of line break

Comment: You can use the [<br /> tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) in place of `\n` which gives line-breaks in HTML.

Comment: I tried but I couldn't figure out how to use it with my above concatenation and assignment

Comment: That depends on how you display your string. When you render it as HTML whitespace is collapsed. If you place the contents of the string within a [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) (preformatted text) tag, it doesn't collapse spaces and keeps the newlines.

Comment: I'm using Sweet alert, I guess they use pre. And even with <br/> it just shows it as a string

Comment: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#html as per docs, as mentioned by @ProudOne

Comment: How are you displaying the alert? If I execute `swal({ text: "Hello World!\nfoo bar baz" })` (JS console on https://sweetalert.js.org) the resulting content of the pop-up does have line breaks. Are you using the string as title?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use `<br>` to create a new line in html. Browsers don't generally respect whitespace unless wrapped in a `<pre>`

Comment: Thanks. How do I write it in the string concatenation? I tried but it didn't work

Comment: `myString += response + "<br />";`

Comment: I tried that, but it just shows the "<br/>" as a string

Comment: How are you using the `myString` inside HTML? If you are setting it using `innerText`, just use `innerHTML` instead.

Comment: using Sweet Alert 2, this string is the error parameter for it

Comment: See the documentation : https://sweetalert2.github.io/#html - looks like it has an 'HTML' property to use with element formatted text.

Comment: @TheArchitect Please consider accepting this answer if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

By default in HTML, new lines, tabs and multiple spaces are collapsed to a single space, and only wrap lines if the width isn't enough.

If you want to preserve the original spacing in display use the CSS property [white-space: pre;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

You can also use the variants `pre-wrap` which keeps wrapping to long lines in addition to the original spacing, or `pre-line` which keeps original linebreaks and wrap long lines but does not display multiple spaces.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<br>` tag in HTML for line break.